# How to shrink extended partition and extend primary partition

Tags: partitioning, arch-linux

Hello to all and thanks in advance.

I did the partitions to the hard drive in a bad way and I need more space to the primary partition in order to install plasma I need 7Gb more or less so it gives me error. I am using arch linux and this is the table of partitions:

[image]

Is there any way to shrink the extended partition and extend primary partition without booting from the live CD and realocating the space?

How could I do that in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No. At minimum you need to have the filesystem unmounted to shrink the filesystem, so booting up with a usb disk or equivalent is inevitable. Also, its relatively risky as you will have to move the start of the extended partition backwards.

That said, you can likely hack around your problem by using symbolic symlinks to move some stuff from your primary partition onto another partition.  (ie by moving directories to the secondary partition and then using **ln -s** to "graft" these into the main tree.)